# unable to get tooltip to work when usingjQuery load() content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having problem getting my tooltip to work when using the jQuery load() function. The tooltip works fine if i don't use load() to load external dynamic data.

I googled and found the i may need to use live(), but I can't figure how to get it to work. Any suggestion?

thank you!!

Here is my scripts:

```
function loadEMERContent(uid) {
    $("#ActionEWPNBook").load("ajaxLoadDATA.cfm?uid="+uid, null, showLoading);
    $("#EWPNBookloading").html('<img src="/masterIncludes/images/ajaxLoading.gif" alt="loading" align="center" />');
}

function showLoading() {
    $("#EWPNBookloading").html('');

}


function simple_tooltip(target_items, name){
 $(target_items).each(function(i){
        $("body").append("<div class='"+name+"' id='"+name+i+"'><p style='padding:5px;'>"+$(this).attr('title')+"</p></div>");
        var my_tooltip = $("#"+name+i);

        $(this).removeAttr("title").mouseover(function(){
                my_tooltip.css({opacity:0.8, display:"none"}).stop().fadeIn(400);
        }).mousemove(function(kmouse){
                my_tooltip.css({left:kmouse.pageX+15, top:kmouse.pageY+15});
        }).mouseout(function(){
                my_tooltip.stop().fadeOut(400);               
        });
    });
}
```

Here is my ajaxLoadDATA.cfm: it returns an unorder list

```
<li><span title="dynamic title here" class="tipthis">date</span></li>
```

Comment: Can you post where you'r calling `simple_tooltip` now?

Comment: Thanks for you response here this is where i call the simple_tooltip.

$(function() {
 simple_tooltip("span.tipthis","tooltip");
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your callback function, you need to run the tooltip code against the new items, like this:

```
function showLoading(data) { //data  = the response text, passed from `.load()`
  $("#EWPNBookloading").html('');
  var items = //get items here, something like $('.giveMeATooltip', data);
  var name = //set name, not sure what you're using for this
  simple_tooltip(items, name);    
}
```

One side tip, if you change this line:

```
 $("body").append("<div class='"+name+"' id='"+name+i+"'><p style='padding:5px;'>"+$(this).attr('title')+"</p></div>");
```

To something like this:

```
$("body").append(
    $("<div></div>", { 'class': name, 'id': name + i }).append(
        $("<p style='padding:5px;'></p>").text($(this).attr('title'))
    )
);
```

Your tooltip generation will be **much** faster due to how jQuery can cache document fragments for reuse.

Comment: +1 for a nice answer, but make sure you are using jQuery 1.4+ for the last example to work :)

Comment: Thanks Nick, I'll try your suggestion and will let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

I use a modified version of [this tooltip](http://cssglobe.com/post/1695/easiest-tooltip-and-image-preview-using-jquery). This version uses `.live` so loaded content will automatically have tooltip functionality. All you need to do is:

1. Add this script to your main page (adding it as an external file is perferred)
2. You need to ensure that the elements that need a tooltip have a `class="tipthis"` and that the tooltip contents are within the title attribute. Also, the tooltip can contain HTML (e.g. `<h1>Tooltip</h1>Hello,<br>World`).
3. You will also need some basic CSS:

   ```
   #tooltip { background: #f7f5d1; color: #333; padding: 5px; width: 300px; }
   ```

Here is the script (using live and it requires jQuery version 1.4+)

```
/* Tooltip script */
this.tooltip = function(){
 // Defaults
 var tooltipSpeed = 300; // fadein speed in milliseconds
 var xOffset = 20; // Don't use negative values here
 var yOffset = 20;

 $('.tipthis').live('mouseover',function(e) {
  this.t = this.title;
  this.title = '';

  $('<div></div>', {
   id : 'tooltip',
   css: {
    display : 'none',
    position: 'absolute',
    zIndex  : 1000,
    top     : (e.pageY - xOffset) + 'px',
    left    : (e.pageX + yOffset) + 'px'
   }
  })
  .html( this.t )
  .appendTo('body');

  $('#tooltip').fadeIn(tooltipSpeed);
 })

 .live('mouseout',function(){
  this.title = this.t;
  $('#tooltip').remove();
 })

 .live('mousemove',function(e){
  $("#tooltip").css({
   top : (e.pageY - xOffset) + 'px',
   left: (e.pageX + yOffset) + 'px'
  });
 })
}
$(document).ready(function(){ tooltip(); });
```

Here is some sample HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="tipthis" title="This is some tooltip content">Hover over me!</a>
```

Comment: Very Nice! Thanks fudgey for your response. I'll try your suggestion tomorrow and let you know if it works or not.

Comment: Thanks fudgey, I opted to go with Nick suggestion because I was able to use my existing codes.